# How to use CORS in Restlet 2.3.1?

Tags: cors, restlet

I'm trying to set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' header for the response. However, the header is not present. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class JsonApplication extends Application
{
    private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8111";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        Server testServer = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8111);        
        JsonApplication jsonApplication = new JsonApplication();

        CorsService corsService = new CorsService();         
        corsService.setAllowedOrigins( new HashSet(Arrays.asList("*")));
        corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);

        jsonApplication.getServices().add( corsService );      

        testServer.setNext( jsonApplication );
        testServer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot()
    {
        Router router = new Router( getContext() );
        router.attach( SERVER_URL + "/", RootResource.class );        
        return router;
    }
}
```

I checked the source code for org.restlet.engine.application.CorsResponseHelper and it contains the following code:

```
public void addCorsResponseHeaders(Request request, Response response) {

String origin = request.getHeaders().getFirstValue("Origin", true);

if (origin == null) {
    // Not a CORS request
    return;
}
...
}
```

So, it appears that the current CORS implementation does not support requests made from a local html-file, since in that case origin == null.

I added some logging to my servlet application:

```
JsonApplication::createInboundRoot()
16:26 MyCorsService()
16:26 myCorsService = wwwdbase.rest.cors.MyCorsService@6e1b241d
16:26 MyCorsService::setAllowedOrigins(), [*]
16:26 services: [org.restlet.service.TunnelService@4c88fe62, 
org.restlet.service.StatusService@68349a5b,
org.restlet.service.DecoderService@77cfd8d3,
org.restlet.service.EncoderService@40c331fb,
org.restlet.service.RangeService@4bb3bc6f,
org.restlet.service.ConnectorService@7990100,
org.restlet.service.ConnegService@e194860,
org.restlet.service.ConverterService@578cfcb1,
org.restlet.service.MetadataService@18a62eb,
org.restlet.service.TaskService@4ed4f2db,
wwwdbase.rest.cors.MyCorsService@6e1b241d]
```

We can see that MyCorsService is available. However, it is never called by the servlet framework. On the other hand, if I run the service (the Java SE version) from IDE, MyCorsService is called. Why do these cases behave differently?

Partial solution: I managed to add the allow origin header by changing the code in org.restlet.engine.header.HeaderUtils

```
if (response.getAccessControlAllowOrigin() != null) 
{          
    addHeader(HeaderConstants.HEADER_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN,
            response.getAccessControlAllowOrigin(), headers);
}
```

to

```
if (response.getAccessControlAllowOrigin() != null) 
{          
    addHeader(HeaderConstants.HEADER_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN,
            response.getAccessControlAllowOrigin(), headers);
}
else
{
    // --- Add in any case!
    //           
    response.setAccessControlAllowOrigin( "*" );
    addHeader(HeaderConstants.HEADER_ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN,
                    response.getAccessControlAllowOrigin(), headers);            
}
```

However, the answer to the question why the servlet framework in Tomcat did not call the cors service is still unknown...

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you have correctly configured the CORS service of Restlet ;-)

In the context of CORS, there are two kinds of requests:

- **Simple requests**. To be short, when you use methods `GET`, `HEAD` and some cases with `POST`. In this case, CORS headers aren't required when doing cross domain requests.
- **Preflighted requests** The other cases where CORS headers are required to do cross domain requests.

So if you simply do a method `GET`, it's normal that you saw nothing. Try with a method `POST` with a JSON content and you will see the CORS headers.

For more details, you can have a look at this link:

- **Understanding and using CORS** - https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/understanding-and-using-cors/

**Edited**

I made a more complete test for your issue. I have two Restlet server launched on different ports (8182 for the resource to be accessed using AJAX, 8183 for the JS application that accesses the resource).

The first one is configured with your code:

```
CorsService corsService = new CorsService();         
corsService.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("*")));
corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);

RestletApplication application = new RestletApplication();
application.getServices().add(corsService);
component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(application);
```

The server resource in it is simple:

```
public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
    @Get
    public TestBean ping() {
        TestBean bean = new TestBean();
        bean.setMessage("pong");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

The second application only uses a Restlet directory to serve static content:

```
@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    router.attach("/static", new Directory(
            getContext(), "clap:///test/static"));
    return router;
}
```

In addition to JQuery library, I added the following HTML file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#id1').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url : 'http://localhost:8182/ping',
           type : 'GET',
           success : function(result, status){
               console.log('ok = '+result);
           },
           error : function(result, status, error){
               console.log('error');
           },
           complete : function(result, status){
                console.log('complete');
           }
        });
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="id1">Click</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is what I have when I clicked on the button "Click" at the header level:

```
// Request
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Host    localhost:8182
Origin  http://localhost:8183
Referer http://localhost:8183/static/test.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0

// Response
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Cred...    true
Access-Control-Allow-Orig...    http://localhost:8183
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Fri, 13 Mar 2015 09:16:48 GMT, Fri, 13 Mar 2015 09:16:48 GMT
Server  Restlet-Framework/2.3.1
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
```

As you can see, the CORS are present ;-)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am developing a RESTful service which returns data in JSON format. A client can develop his own browser-based UI and interact with the server using AJAX calls. Cross-domain AJAX calls are forbidden by default, so even when using GET, CORS (or, JSONP) is required. 

However, I tested the server calls by writing the request url directly in the browser's address bar. Obviously, that was not a proper AJAX call, so no wonder if the header was missing. I implicitly assumed that if CORS is correctly configured, the Restlet framework always includes the header...

Comment: I edited my answer with a more complete test. It appears that on an AJAX request, the CORS headers are there ;-)

Comment: I have now installed my application under a localhost Tomcat server. If I call the service from a local html-file via jQuery Ajax, I get the response:'Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/rest/authentication. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS' So, it seems that CORS does not work!?

Comment: In the html-file-based call, there is a request header 'Origin null'. Maybe this is the source of the problem. If so, how could it be solved?

Comment: Please edit this answer, it is misleading. "Simple requests" also require CORS headers, which your linked blog post confirms.