# Restlet + JAXRS extension - how to use filters?

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, cors, restlet

I have a REST service implemented in Restlet + JAXRS extension.
At a certain point, I had to add the CORS headers to responses. 
I have a lot of REST calls, and adding by hand the headers as this is working:

```
        return Response.status(200).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type").
                header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location, Content-Disposition").
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS").
                entity(fsJSON).build();
```

but I'd like to use filters in order to add those headers to all the responses, without adding those manually. I found a lot of examples of using filters in JAX-RS, like those:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html

http://javatech-blog.blogspot.it/2015/04/jax-rs-filters-example.html

http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/04/filtering-jax-rs-entities-with-standard-security-annotations/

But I can't understand how to integrate them with Restlet + JAX-RS environment. For example, I can't see the ContainerResponseFilter class anywhere. 
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a JaxRS application within Restlet, you create a `JaxRsApplication` (see this link: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.2/extensions/jaxrs). This class extends the standard application of Restlet. The latter provides the way to configure services on it using the `getServices` method.

So in your case, you don't need to use filters...

See this answer regarding the configuration of the CorsService of Restlet: [How to use CORS in Restlet 2.3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988671/how-to-use-cors-in-restlet-2-3-1/28991414#28991414).

Here a way to configure CORS within a Restlet JaxRS application:

```
Component comp = new Component();
Server server = comp.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8182);

JaxRsApplication application = new JaxRsApplication(comp.getContext());
application.add(new ExampleApplication());

CorsService corsService = new CorsService();         
corsService.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("*")));
corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);

application.getServices().add(corsService);
component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(application);
```

Otherwise JAX-RS filters aren't supported by the corresponding extensions of Restlet. To add a filter, you need to add it as a Restlet filter in front of the application, as described below:

```
JaxRsApplication application = new JaxRsApplication(comp.getContext());
application.add(new ExampleApplication());

MyRestletFilter filter = new MyRestletFilter();
filter.setNext(application);

component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(filter);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I added explanation regarding filters in general regarding the JAX-RS extension...